Iodine/iodide electrochemistry help
I have an electrochemistry experiment with iodine in solution.
I am initially wanting to quantify the iodide in solution and extrapolate the concentration of I2(aq) and I3-(aq) in solution from this using an O1 redox (Pt) electrode. I will also be using an R2 reference electrode.
I will be buffering with 0.1M potassium hydrogen phthalate and 0.1M KNO3 at pH 4. Theoretically to force any iodine speciation into I- form and quantify from there.
There is an added complexity to the testing as this will be performed over 2 instruments with each having either the PT or ISE electrode and one at a time measuring in conjunction with the reference electrode.
As iodine is self ionising and the reactions I2 + 2e- -> 2I- and I3- + 2e- -> 3I-. I am wondering what the redox reactions at the electrodes will be in order to calculate Ecell?
As I am limited by the instrumentation, are there any other factors I will need to account for? And for K which should the red or ox to calculate the I2 and I3?
Any help is appreciated as I am new to this.
Thanks

Which reducing agent are you using to transform $\ce{I2}$ into iodide ions ?

Consider formatting guides for texts and formulas/equations/expressions
